How to derive quadratic equation?
If we derive the formula for linear equation $y=ax +b$ from two points on a coordinate  plane, could we derive the quadratic equation (not the formula, but the equation itself) $y=ax^2 + bx+c$ in a similar way? If not, how do we derive the equation from scratch?

The method is essentially the same as for a linear equation. Substitute the ($3$) points in the general quadratic equation, then solve the resulting linear system for $a,b,c$.

You can just write down any equation you want and wonder about its solutions.

Derived or defined?

To derive the equation of a quadratic function  $y = ax^2 + bx + c$ from points on a coordinate plane, we can follow a process similar to deriving the linear equation, but with additional complexity because a quadratic function has three unknowns: $a$ ,  $b$ , and $c$ . Unlike a linear equation, which requires two points, a quadratic equation requires three points to uniquely determine the values of  $a$ ,  $b$ , and  $c$.

For a linear equation:
Assume that $~(x_1,y_1)~$ and $~(x_2,y_2)~$ are distinct points on the line $~y = mx + b,$ which is assumed to not be a vertical line.
This implies that $~x_1 - x_2 \neq 0.$
Then $~y_1 = mx_1 + b~$ and $~y_2 = mx_2 + b.~$
So,
$$y_1 - mx_1 = y_2 - mx_2 \implies m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2}.$$
So, since $~m~$ is now determined, you can solve for $~b~$ via
$$b = y_1 - mx_1.$$

For a quadratic equation:
Assume that $~(x_1,y_1), ~(x_2,y_2)~$ and $~(x_3,y_3)~$ all satisfy the equation $~y = ax^2 + bx + c,~$ where $~x_1, ~x_2, ~$ and $~x_3~$ represent three distinct values.
Then

Eq-1: $~y_1 = ax^2_1 + bx_1 + c.$
Eq-2: $~y_2 = ax^2_2 + bx_2 + c.$
Eq-3: $~y_3 = ax^2_3 + bx_3 + c.$

Since $~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, ~$ and $~y_1, ~y_2, ~y_3~$ are presumed known, you now have three linear equations in the three variables (to be solved for), $~a, ~b~$ and $~c.$
So,

Eq-4 : [Eq-1] - [Eq-2] $~(y_1 - y_2) = a(x_1^2 - x_2^2) + b(x_1 - x_2).$

Eq-5 : [Eq-1] - [Eq-3] $~(y_1 - y_3) = a(x_1^2 - x_3^2) + b(x_1 - x_3).$


Keeping in mind that $~x_1, ~x_2, ~x_3, ~$ and $~y_1, ~y_2, ~y_3~$ are all known, you now have two linear equations in the two unknowns $~a~$ and $~b.~$
For ease of syntax:

let $~P = y_1 - y_2.$

let $~Q = y_1 - y_3.$

let $~R = x^2_1 - x^2_2.$

let $~S = x^2_1 - x^2_3.$

let $~T = x_1 - x_2.$

let $~U = x_1 - x_3.$


Then:
$$P = aR + bT, ~Q = aS + bU \implies $$
$$PU = aRU + bTU, ~QT = aST + bTU.$$
Subtracting these equations gives
$$PU - QT = a(RU - ST) \implies a = \frac{PU - QT}{RU - ST}. \tag1 $$
Note that
$$RU - ST = 0 \implies (x^2_1 - x^2_2)(x_1 - x_3) - (x^2_1 - x^2_3)(x_1 - x_2) = 0 \implies $$
$$(x_1 - x_2)(x_1 - x_3) [ ~(x_1 + x_2) - (x_1 + x_3) ~] = 0 \implies $$
$$(x_1 - x_2)(x_1 - x_3)(x_2 - x_3) = 0. \tag2 $$
However, the conclusion in (2) above is impossible, because it is assumed that $~x_1, ~x_2, ~$ and $~x_3~$ are all distinct.
Therefore, the denominator on the RHS in (1) above, $~RU - ST,~$ is not equal to $~0.$
So, $~a~$ is now known, and (similarly) $~T \neq 0.~$ So $~b~$ can be solved for via (for example)
$$P = aR + bT \implies b = \frac{P - aR}{T}.$$
So, $~a~$ and $~b~$ are now known, so $~c~$ can be solved for via (for example)
$$y_1 = ax^2_1 + bx_1 + c \implies c = y_1 - ax^2_1 - bx_1.$$

The above explains that we can derive a quadratic equation from three different nonlinear points, but it assumes that the points follow the quadratic equation  y = ax^2 + bx + c . But how did we come up with the model  y = ax^2 + bx + c ? Linear equations can be derived from two points with no extra assumptions. Was the quadratic equation model derived by trial and error, or is there a mathematical idea behind formulating it?

@AbiyErmias Just as all first degree equations are expressible as $$y = ax + b ~: ~a \neq 0,$$ all second degree equations are expressible as $$y = ax^2 + bx + c ~: ~a \neq 0.$$

The comments explain the method, but I will give an example.
Suppose a quadratic function contains the points (1,-1), (-1,-3), (2,6).
The function has the form $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, and the coordinates above imply $f(1) = -1, f(-1) = -3$, and $f(2) = 6$.
Substituting the points into the quadratic function yields the 3 variable system:
$-1 = a + b + c$
$ -3 = a - b + c$
$ 6 = 4a +2b + c$
Solving the system yields the unique solution $a = 2, b = 1, c = -4$.
Therefore  $f(x) = 2x^2 + x -4$.
